# GWT java.util.Date serialization

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, gwt

I'm building a scraper a GWT based web app, to automatize some tasks we need to do on interval basis. There are two date pickers where to choose start date and end date. I see that there is an algorithm to convert Javascript dates to strings to send along the http request.
For instance:

11-08-2015 is `VDkLYWA`

11-09-2015 is `VDpU$GA`

11-10-2015 is `VDuej2A`

I tried to dig in the JS code but, as you may imagine, with not much luck.
I'm guessing there is an non-obfuscated version of the de-serialization in the GWT project [source code](https://github.com/gwtproject) so that I can reverse-engineer it, but I have no experience with GWT and don't know exactly where to look.
Maybe someone has already solved this problem or can point me to some resources?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with passing dates as Strings in any format that you like (i.e. 20151108 or 2015-11-08)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT has a class `com.google.gwt.lang.LongLib` (inside gwt-dev.jar) which converts date long value to string conversion. This conversion is basically Base64 conversion. Below is a sample how it works:

```
Date d = new Date(115, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0); //2015-11-08 00:00:00
String s = LongLib.toBase64(d.getTime());
System.out.println(s); //Prints VDjNlRA
```

So, either you can include this jar in your application to do this conversion or you can write the same algorithm in javascript.

Comment: I'm not a GWT/Java expert, I found the `longToBase64` method in `gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStream.java` file, is that the algorithm I need to implement in javascript?

Comment: Yes. You need to implement the same algorithm in JS. https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/AbstractSerializationStream.java

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!